# Can "Made" be used as adjective also?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, be

Sentence: 
1.Sweets are made from milk.
2.This building is made of stone and brick.
In above "made" is adjective or "verb"?
Since "made" is followed by "be verb form" in above sentences.

Comment: The verb "made" in your examples is in the passive voice. (plural) "Oranges are grown in California", and (Past Passive) "Napoleon was defeated in the battle of Waterloo"

Comment: Thanks, Yes i noticed that. Just got confused about 'made' after reading "they have filled the bag with coins" and "the bag is full of coins" in 1st filled is verb and in 2nd full is adjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***made*** is the past and past participle of *make*.

*made* is an adjective usually used in combining form, e.g., handmade, tailor-made

As @Davo points out, it's also used as an adjective in "a made man."

See [made](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/made) Oxford Dictionaries; also look in the same source for the definition of *make*, which has many meanings and uses.

Comment: Okay so i looked up for both made and make in that dictionary and it seems as stated by "Mari-Lou A" that  in my sentences it was "verb". "Made" is used as adjective in combination like handmade. Thanks!